How do i define content for flowfram using labels?
I am writing a two column layout article which contains a side panel, and a main content panel.
Since the content for both the side panel and the main panel content comes from user input, there's no way for me to know where page breaks might occur. So to maintain the layout, I'm opting to use flowfram. But the problem here is that I am unable to assign the side panel content to the "sideFrame" and main panel content to the "mainFrame" in my latex file?
How would I do that?
This is kind of what I am expecting:
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=.4in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\gap}
\setlength{\gap}{20pt}

\newlength{\sidePanelWidth}
\setlength{\sidePanelWidth}{1.8in}

\newlength{\mainPanelWidth}
\setlength{\mainPanelWidth}{\textwidth - \sidePanelWidth - \gap}

\newflowframe{\sidePanelWidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[sideFrame]
\newflowframe{\mainPanelWidth}{\textheight}{\sidePanelWidth + \gap}{0pt}[mainFrame]

\begin{flowframe}{sideFrame}
    \lipsum[1-2]  % Example content for the side frame
\end{flowframe}

\begin{flowframe}{mainFrame}
    \lipsum[1-2]  % Example content for the main frame
\end{flowframe}

\end{document}

Edit: added a bit more context, code and the reference that I am following.
This is the doc that I have been following: Creating Flow Frames for Posters, Brochures or Magazines
using flowfram.sty version 1.17 - Nicola L. C. Talbot

Welcome. // Can you please add the missing parts to make it compile? Thank you

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do. Provide minimal code with your best attempt, but make it executable. And paste the output into the question. Also explain what specifically is wrong in that output. A sketch or a retouched image of the output to show how it should end up can be very helpful in really understanding the problem.

Apart from the code also the workflow is a bit unclear. How do the users currently provide their content to you? Do you have any influence over this process? For example if you can ask them to provide two separate files then it would probably be easy to add it at the right position in the code using the \input command, something like \begin{Mainframe}\input{userxyz-main-code}\end{mainFrame}\begin{sideFrame}\input{userxyz-side-code}\end{sideFrame}.

@MS-SPO I added in some additional code, but I highly doubt it's going to work that way

@Fran Hi, I tried to make the code executable, but I just am unable to use flowfram package. I have attached a reference image for what I am expecting.

@Marijn Hey, so I will be using python to inject the user input to the input areas in a python string, which will then be rendered to a pdf using a subprocess.run() on lualatex. I tried using pdf generation libraries in python, but the results were disappointing, so I tried manually generating the layout in latex, which gave me a satisfactory result, but it has one problem that I had to manually adjust layouts in case of page breaks.
So I am hoping that using flowfram, I might be able to just inject the user string (in side and main panel environments) and generate the desired pdf.

@Marijn The only other easier option that I have, is to generate the two PDFs (one for side panel and the other for main panel) separately and combine the two together using something like pypdf2. But I want to try and give flowfram one shot.

@RohanGunjalZeenX1  You have a working example
here which you can use as the starting point. However, for this simple layout consider the switch to the tufte classes  or use  paracol or vwcol.

May I suggest making use of one of the samples shipped with flowfram as a tutorial. Instead of our trying to make your code work, perhaps it will be useful for you to start with the code provided by the package and work backwards? It might also be a useful "tutorial"? sample-brochure.tex looks useful . . .

@Fran That's a good find, I will read more and update if I find a good solution.

@bishopcranmer Will read that, thanks!

You would probably be better off using paracol.  Euther that or make one column a dynamic frame and the other a flow frame.

@JohnKormylo okay, will try it out
